# Update property of every node with different set of properties using cypher query

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am using Bolt Driver to load the csv data into Graph. The Create and Delete operations are done very well but I am stuck with the update operations.

Since, each node contains different set of properties. How can I write the  Cypher Query using SET property.
**Approach 1:**
**My CSV Data:**

```
2,attribute1,0.8,attribute2,0.1
5,attribute1,0.5,attribute2,0.2,attribute3,0.7
4,....
```

**Approach 2:**
**My CSV Data:**

```
 id,attribute1,attribute2,attribute3
    2,   0.8,   0.1,    Null
    5,   Null,  0.2,  ,0.7
    4,....
```

If the first approach is impossible. Then I wish to opt for the second approach. In this approach how can Iterate over each attribute and make if else kind of execution using cypher.

Answer (score 1):

for the 2nd approach:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "URL" AS row
MATCH (n:Label) WHERE n.id = row.id 
SET n += row
```

This adds / overrides properties.

If you want to replace all properties use `SET n = row`